# How to ensure execution order

Tags: java, multithreading, mongodb, database

What are the different ways and the best way to ensure the order of execution when different database operations are involved and one operations depends on other operations.
Something in a code like this:

```
String countryName = "name";
Country countryObj = new Country();
countryObj.setName(countryName);
countryObj.setStates(new ArrayList<State>());
// update database
PersistenceManager manager = new PersistenceManager();
List<Country> countries = manager.getAllCountries();                    
if (countries != null && !countries.isEmpty()) {
    for (Country country2 : countries) {
        if (country2.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(countryName)) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
manager.saveCountry(countryObj, country);
```

Here  the manager.getAllCountries() retrieves all the countries from the database and manager.saveCountry depends on previous operation

Comment: Does your database/ORM support transactions?

Comment: My database is MongoDB, and I think it does not support transactions

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to start from the point of looking at modeling your data to use [atomic operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-data-for-atomic-operations/).

What you are describing is an insert data if not present.  You could do this with an [upsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-parameter) and looking from your logic if the country exists you don't want to change anything (as you just return out of the method).  So you can just use the [$setOnInsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) operator - so that you **only** save the values of your `countryObj` if it doesn't already exist.

The last hurdle is the name matching - as you are testing for equivalence against lowercased versions of the names - you could use a [regular expression](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) in your query but that would do a full scan of your documents in the collection - so another alternative is to store the lowercased name to match against.

An example that queries and inserts if not present using shell syntax is below:

```
db.collection.update(
   {lname: countryName.toLowerCase()},
   { $setOnInsert: { name: countryName, states: [{name: "Victoria"}]  } },
   { upsert: true }
)
```

Of course if you wanted to update any information if the `country` does exist you can also use the `$set` operator to update even if the country exists.